Is materialism wrong?
The matter in brain cells is recycled every few days. If materialism was correct then you would have a life expectancy of five days and the rest of your life would be a different person.
Is materialism obviously wrong by its own assumptions or does materialism have other complexity beyond humans literally just being material?
